# Docusign - Managed Solution file - Dynamics CRM

Tags: docusignapi

We're working within our environment to clean up solutions and require the managed solution file for Docusign, for placing in the lower environment.  We don't want the newest one but our current version, so that we can follow an upgrade path.

The version we're after is 5.2.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, you want to install the solution in another environment but you lost the file. You should try to contact the docusign team.

https://www.docusign.com/solutions/microsoft/dynamics-365-CRM

Maybe you can download the file on the website, but I don't have access since I don't have an account.